# Magento, getFinalPrice()

Tags: php, magento

I have the following code in an Observer on the cart in a module i've written

```
  $product   = $this->_getProduct($productId);
  Mage::log("Outside: " . $product->getFinalPrice());
  // product needs to be visible
  if ($product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
      Mage::log("Inside: " . $product->getFinalPrice());
```

The results of this are

Outside: 110
Outside: 100
Inside: 100

In my basket I have 1 configurable product with a base price of 100, but the option added costs +10 so in the cart itself the text reads 110.

Outside is printed twice as the code runs over every item in the cart, only the subproduct 'is visible'

How can I reliably get the actual price of the product I'm buying? This also needs to take into account the price if the parent product has been set with a sale price / certain sub products have sale prices.

There is surely a way to just get this items 'purchase' price?

Comment: Have you tried using ```$product->getBasePrice()```

Comment: getBasePrice was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `$product->getBasePrice()` you should get the values you are after.